# Java static methods accessing private variables

Tags: java, variables, static, scope, private

I was under the impression that private non-static variables could only be accessed by methods called on the object that the variables reside in, but this is not the case. Could someone please explain the reasoning behind why the following compiles and runs?

```
public class Sandbox {
    private String _privateString = "unmodified";
    public static void setPrivateString(String str, Sandbox s) {
        s._privateString = str;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return _privateString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sandbox s = new Sandbox();
        setPrivateString("modified", s);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
modified
```

**EDIT:** The same is true in C#.

Comment: You could have modified the `_privateString` directly from the `main()` as its in the same class.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Private member variables of class A can be accessed (i.e. read/written to) by **any** method of class A (static or non-static), so in your example, since the method changing the string is a method of the same class the member belongs to, it is granted access to the variable.

The reason is because a class is considered a self-contained body of logic (i.e. a specific implementation), so it makes sense that privacy is contained within a class; there is no reason to exclude static methods from that access right, since they are also part of the specific implementation the class provides.

Comment: So any instance of a class has access to all private variables of all other instances of that class?

Comment: Exactly! Which at first might seem strange, although makes sense when you think about it in terms of a class being one single implementation.

Comment: @T.K. So for example, `public void changeOther(String changeTo, Sandbox s) { s._privateString=changeTo; }` can be executed on another instance altogether: `s1.changeOther("blah", s2);`

Comment: Okay. Is there a design pattern that would enforce the rule of only the instance to which a variable `a` belongs can access `a`? Or should I ask that in another question, rather than in a comment, and open it up for more people to answer?

Answer (score 4):

The rule is simple:

*member methods of a class can access and modify private members of the same class **regardless of their visibility**.*

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing `visibility` with `scope`. The instance variables are in the scope of an instance, so they cannot be accessed in a static method directly, but only with an instance reference qualifier: `s._privateString` in your case.

However, this does not mean that instance variables are not *visible* for a static method inside the same class, as `private` means visible inside the class (for any member with any scope).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in some other posts, Java's visibility system is class-based, not an object-based one.

Note that this is utilized in the compiler: When you have nested classes and you access a private field of the outer class, a public synthetic static method is generated to allow the access. It is usually named "access$0" etc. You can create a bytecode that violates encaplulation without the Reflection API by using these synthetic methods. You can also access them from the Reflection API without enabling access to private members. Many crazy things can be done...

If there was not such visibility system, compiler probably would need to compile it elsehow.

... Hoewver, the end-programmer usually don't need to know this detail. IDEs don't include synthetic methods in code completion and I hope that compilers (except Jasmin) don't allow you to use it. So if you don't generate bytecode and don't use Reflection API and you ignore these methods in the stacktrace, you probably don't need to know this detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is compiled because inside **setPrivateString(String str, Sandbox s)** you are accessing the private variable **_privateString** by reference variable s.

**A non-static member can only access by instance variable from the static API.**

Check this code

```
public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sandbox s = new Sandbox();
        // testAccess();// If you uncomment this line you will get compile time error
        s.testAccess();//can only access in this way
    }

    private void testAccess() {
        System.out.println("can only access by instance variable from static method");
    }
}
```